# How do I select specific rows with sed?

Tags: awk, sed

In [manual of sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#sed-addresses), the page show the methods to select specific lines but in a range.
How can I select spcific lines which have no rules?

```sh
seq 10
```

For example, how can I change line 1, 3, 7 to 11?
I tried use `seq 10 | sed '1s/[0-9]/10/;3s/[0-9]/10/;7s/[0-9]/10/'`, but this looks complex and unclear.
Is there a way to do this easier?

Comment: Clearer? `seq 15 | sed '1 ba; 3 ba; 7,11 ba; b; :a; s/[0-9]/10/'`

Comment: By the way, the last substitution in the code of the PO should be `7,11s/[0-9]/10/` and not only `7s/[0-9]/10/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
printf '%ds/[0-9]/10/\n' {1,3,{7..11}} | sed -f - file
```

Convert the numeric sequence (by way of bash brace expansion) into  a series of sed commands and pass them as stdin to the file option to a sed invocation using `file` as the input file.

Or as the OP might wish:

```
printf '%ds/[0-9]/10/\n' {1,3,{7..11}} | sed -f - <(seq 10)
```

Another way to write the same solution:

```
seq 10 | sed $(printf '%ds/[0-9]/10/;' {1,3,{7..11}})
```

Yet another way:

```
<<<"1,3,7 to 11" sed -E 's/$/,/;s/,/ba;/g;s/\s*(to|-|\.\.)\s*([0-9]+)/,\2ba;/g;s/;ba//g' |
sed -f - -e 'b;:a;s/[0-9]/10/' <(seq 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be efficiently done in `awk` program. Create an `awk` variable named `lines` and give all the line numbers there with comma separated form which you want to change. You could also give a range eg: `7-11` your case, which I have used in my program too.

Pass your Input_file to this program and this will substitute digit with `10` as per your shown attempts but this will only print output on terminal. Once you are Happy with results then append  `> temp && mv temp Input_file` to following code, which will perform inplace save into Input_file.

```
awk -v lines="1,3,7-11" '
BEGIN{
  num=split(lines,arr,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
     if(arr[i]~/-/){
        split(arr[i],arr2,"-")
        start=arr2[1]
        while(start<=arr2[2]){
           subArr[start++]
        }
     }
     else{ subArr[arr[i]] }
  }
}
(FNR in subArr){
   sub(/[0-9]/,"10")
}
1' Input_file
```

Comment: In my humble opinion, is is not easier than `seq 10 | sed '1s/[0-9]/10/;3s/[0-9]/10/;7s/[0-9]/10/'`, which was asked by the PO.

Comment: @PierreFrançois, IMHO this is easier(logic wise, maintaining wise), you give only line numbers and you need to write so many substitutions, lets say there are 100 or 1000 lines where we need to perform substitutions, will OP or anyone write 100 or 1000 times substitutions, then this will help just give line number and you are All set. This code even handles range eg: `7-11` line numbers too in dynamic manner(where you can just give it in variable and tat will be taken care in code then).

Answer (score 1):

If your aim is clarity, does the code below meet your requirements?

```
seq 10 | awk '(NR == 1) || (NR == 3) || ((NR >= 7) && (NR <= 11)){gsub(/[0-9]/,"10")} {print}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use awk:

```
$ seq 10 | awk '
    BEGIN {
        split("1 3 7",tmp)
        for (i in tmp) {
            tgts[tmp[i]]
        }
    }
    NR in tgts { sub(/[0-9]/, 10) }
    { print }
'
10
2
10
4
5
6
10
8
9
10
```

or if you wanted to include the ability to specify a range as the other answers do:

```
$ seq 10 | awk '
    BEGIN {
        split("1 3 7-11", tmp)
        for (i in tmp) {
            n = split(tmp[i], range, /-/)
            for (j=range[1]; j <= range[n]; j++) {
                tgts[j]
            }
        }
    }
    NR in tgts { sub(/[0-9]/, 10) }
    { print }
'
10
2
10
4
5
6
10
10
10
100
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use perl one-liner:

```
seq 10 | perl -lane 's/[0-9]/10/ if (grep {$_ == $.} (1,3,7..11));print'
10
2
10
4
5
6
10
10
10
100
```

`sed` is not suitable when condition gets complicated.
The sed solution Cyrus provided in the comment and [potong's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68510207/5403468) are both very good.